# querySelectorAll('input:not([type="hidden"]):not([value=""])') keeps returning elements although the inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to fetch all empty inputs (`value=""`) from my form.

```
var inputsEmpty = loginForm.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="hidden"]):not([value=""])');
```

Keeps returning elements

> 0: input#companyName.form-control
>
> 1: input#userName.form-control
>
> 2: input#password.form-control

although they are not empty (clicking on them in the console shows `value:''`.

I tried using jQuery thinking it might be something with the queryselector

```
var inputsEmpty = $('input:not([type="hidden"]):not([value=""]):not([id="email"])');
```

I get the same result.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform" action="/login/user_login" method="POST" novalidate>

    <h3 class="text-center m-b-20">Sign In</h3>

    <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name='company_name' id="companyName"  placeholder="Company Name" required="1" minlength="6" maxlength="30"/> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_name" id="userName" autocomplete="off" placeholder="User Name" placeholder="Username" required="1" minlength="6" maxlength="30"> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name='password' id="password" placeholder="Password" required="1" minlength="6" maxlength="30"> 
        </div>
    </div> .......
```

JS:

```
const loginForm = document.querySelector('#loginform');
const submit    = loginForm.querySelector('#submitBtn');
// const $loginForm = $('#loginform');

bootstrapValidate(
    '#companyName',
    'min:6:Invalid company name|max:30:Invalid company name|required:This field is required'
);

bootstrapValidate(
    '#userName',
    'min:3:Invalid company name|max:30:Invalid company name|required:This field is required'
);

bootstrapValidate(
    '#password',
    'min:6:Password too short (6 min)|max:30:Password too long (30 max)|required:This field is required'
);

function toSubmit() {

    var notValid    = loginForm.querySelector('.is-invalid');
    // var inputsEmpty = loginForm.querySelector('input:not([value=""])');
    // var inputsEmpty = loginForm.querySelector('input:not([value]):not([value=""])');
    var inputsEmpty = loginForm.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="hidden"]):not([value=""])');
    // var inputsEmpty = loginForm.querySelector('input[value=""]:not([type="hidden"])');
    // var inputsEmpty = $('input:not([type="hidden"]):not([value=""]):not([id="email"])');

    console.log(notValid);
    console.log(inputsEmpty);

    if (notValid || inputsEmpty)
        return false;
    else 
        loginForm.submit();
}

submit.onclick = toSubmit;
```

How do I list only empty inputs

Comment: `I'm trying to fetch all empty inputs (value="") `   So why are you using `not`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because value is an attribute, when you do a selector on it, it's only the initial value that will be selected on (aka the attribute), because you change the value, the selector will no longer work.

So another solution is to check the value directly in Javascript.

The `inputsEmpty` check, simply uses the normal selector, but this time use querySelectorAll, converts into a simply array, and uses the `Array.some` to find if any of those are blank.  `value==""`.

Below is a working snippet showing this.

ps. to work with your code, simply replace your inputsEmpty, with this one.

```js
document.addEventListener("input", () => {
  var inputsEmpty = 
    Array.from(document.
      querySelectorAll('input:not([type=hidden])'))
        .some(function (e) {
          return e.value == "";
        });   
  document.querySelector("#isEmpty").classList.
    toggle("hidden", !inputsEmpty);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value=""/>
<input type="text" value=""/>
<input type="text" value="hello"/>

<div id="isEmpty">Empty</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I keep getting `null` as a result in all cases (with text in the inputs and without).  i tried changing my variable value to `var inputsEmpty = document.querySelector('input[value=""]:not([type=hidden])');` instead of `login.FormquerySelector('input[value=""]:not([type=hidden])');` and this didn't resolve the problem. It should work but it doesn't. What else can be the problem?

Comment: It's maybe best if you show a working snippet of the problem, because as can be seen from the snippet above, it just returns the 1 expected input.

Comment: Ah yes,..  It's because attributes are not computed values,.  I've updated the snippet to do it another way.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means and what the solution does, can you add comments to a few rows in the code?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain in more detail,  just copying the `inputsEmpty` line, and replace with yours should do it.